# Bounding the loss for kernel regularization algorithms

Tags: regularization, ridge-regression, statistical-learning

Some learning bounds depend on a quantity $M$ that is the maximum loss a learning algorithm can have: so $L(h(x),y) \leq M$, where $h(x)$ is the prediction of the model, and $y$ is the label, and $L$ is some loss function such as square or hinge loss.

I'm interested in explicitly calculating $M$ or obtaining an expression for $M$. I'm looking at kernel regularization algorithms that minimize an objective of the form:
$$\frac{1}{m}\sum_i L(h(x_i),y_i) + \lambda ||h||_K^2$$
such as ridge regression or SVM's.